# Ubuntu GNOME - What happens when I click on a Dash Icon?

Tags: gnome

My question is related to a desktop system running Ubuntu 16.04 with Gnome.

How can I detect what (binary, script, ...) will be executed when I click on a icon in the Dash (icon bar), on the left side of the desktop?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Those icons are provided by `.desktop` files, which also specify which program to run.

You can find `.desktop` files in `$HOME/.local/share/applications/`, `$HOME/.gnome/apps/` and `/usr/share/applications/`.

The `locate` command (`man locate`) will help you find `.desktop` files, and, within each `.desktop` file there a line starting with `Exec=`. It specifies the program to be run.

Comment: I'll see the system on friday, then i will give feedback.